# Sql - which letter of the alphabet is not in the names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner at SQL

I need to find out which letter of the alphabet is not in a list of names as first character.

How can I do that?

To look for a specific letter I can use the `LIKE` operator. However I don't know what to use to look for the letter that is not in the list....

The query I have to find the different first letter of the emailadresses is:

```
select left(EmailAddress,1), count(left(EmailAddress,1)
from Customers
order by left(EmailAdress,1)
```

There is no e-mail adress that start with a U.

But which query I can use to get that result?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please add the tag.

Comment: @stickybit I am using sql server

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a table of all letters. You can use an ad hoc derived table using `UNION ALL` and `FROM`-less `SELECT`s. One method then is to use a correlated subquery and `NOT EXISTS` to check for letters not in the first position of any e-mail address.

```
SELECT l.letter
       FROM (SELECT 'a' letter
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'b' letter
             ...
             SELECT 'y' letter
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'z' letter) l
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM customers c
                                WHERE left(lower(emailaddress), 1) = l.letter);
```

Answer (score 0):

One could left join to letters and filter the unmatched.

The example below uses a recursive CTE to generate the letters.

```
WITH RCTE_LETTERS AS
(
  SELECT CHAR(ASCII('a')) AS Letter, ASCII('a') AS Code
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CHAR(code+1), code+1
  FROM RCTE_LETTERS
  WHERE code < ASCII('z')
)
, CTE_FIRST_LETTERS AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
     LOWER(LEFT(EmailAddress,1)) AS FirstLetter
    FROM Customers
)
SELECT l.Letter
FROM RCTE_LETTERS AS l
LEFT JOIN CTE_FIRST_LETTERS AS fl
ON fl.FirstLetter = l.Letter
WHERE fl.FirstLetter IS NULL
ORDER BY l.Letter;
```

Or use an `EXCEPT`

```
WITH RCTE_LETTERS AS
(
  SELECT CHAR(ASCII('a')) AS Letter, ASCII('a') AS Code
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CHAR(code+1), code+1
  FROM RCTE_LETTERS
  WHERE code < ASCII('z')
)
, CTE_FIRST_LETTERS AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
     LOWER(LEFT(EmailAddress,1)) AS FirstLetter
    FROM Customers
)
SELECT Letter FROM RCTE_LETTERS
EXCEPT
SELECT FirstLetter FROM CTE_FIRST_LETTERS
ORDER BY Letter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO

SELECT left(e.EmailAddress,1) AS Letter, COUNT(left(e.EmailAddress,1)) AS CountEmailLetter
FROM Person.Person p INNER JOIN person.EmailAddress e ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
WHERE left(e.EmailAddress,1) NOT IN
    (
        SELECT Char(number+65) 
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
        WHERE name IS NULL AND number < 26
    )
GROUP BY left(e.EmailAddress,1)
ORDER BY left(e.EmailAddress,1)
```